# Missing video source with Video module

Tags: 6, files

I am running Drupal 6.22 and updated the [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module to version 6.x-4.4 and [FFmpeg Wrapper](http://drupal.org/project/ffmpeg_wrapper) to 6.x-2.0-alpha1. Before I was using the swftools to show the videos, but now I wanted to try the HTML5 way. So there are videos in mp4-format (placed in the folder "original") and the converted ones in flv-format (in folder "converted"). After the discribed updates unfortunately no video is showing up - the problem seems to be quite similar. When I edit the content type ("Manage fields" --> "Display fields") and I select "Generic files", everything works as expected. A link to the mp4-File is displayed. But when I choose "Video" the path to the file is missing (only the jpg thumbnail is working correctly), it outputs only this whitout any  tag:

```
<video width="600" height="338" preload="auto" controls="controls" poster="URL TO JPG HERE.jpg" autoplay="autoplay">
</video>
```

Do you have any idea on how I could find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This only works when you also have an MP4 output format. The original video is not used as a source.

Comment: Uh I missed this answer, thanks anyway! I still have the problem, but I don't understand your answer completely. How can I add an "MP4 output format" or see if I have it?

Comment: You need to add or enable an MP4 preset in the video module settings page.